# Python asyncio coroutines

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have an issue where I want an asynchronous function to run 3 coroutines, but it ends up running 2, sometimes only 1. Here is what the code looks like:

```
async def myfunction():
  await coroutine1()
  await coroutine2()
  await coroutine3()
```

Is there any way to ensure that all these 3 coroutines are executed one after another?

Comment: That’s exactly how you’d do that. Why isn’t it always running all three? Is one of them raising an exception?

Comment: None of them raise an exception, though sometimes the last coroutine wouldn't execute, I've fixed the problem now, using tasks = asyncio.gather(c1(), c2(), c3()) and then loop.ensure_future(*tasks)

Answer (score -2):

Found the solution,

```
tasks = asyncio.gather(coroutine1(), coroutine2(), coroutine3())
loop.ensure_future(*tasks)
```

Comment: That will run them simultaneously, not one after another.

Comment: `asyncio.gather()` runs the task in parallel, not sequentially. Second, it only returns _one_ task, so `*tasks` in `ensure_future` is incorrect. (It might appear to work because `Future` defines `__iter__`, but it is not the intended way to use it.) Finally, there is no method `ensure_future` on the event loop, did you mean `asyncio.ensure_future()`?